# Is it better to use a Yes/No question or offer the actual values?

Tags: web-app, question-answer

Which radio option is better for a web application in real estate?

Choice A)

```
List property publicly? 
( ) Yes.  Make the property viewable from my home page. 
( ) No.  Hide the property from my home page.
```

Choice B)

```
( ) List property publicly.  Make the property viewable from my home page. 
( ) Do not list property publicly.  Hide the property from my home page.
```

I've looked around and haven't found this exact question asked, though have seen other questions related to [horizontal/vertical alignment](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21085/yes-no-radio-buttons-vertical-or-horizontal) and some about [third option choices](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20374/multiple-choice-with-yes-no-and-no-answer).

I'd also welcome any other tips as far as how to structure this required question.

Comment: the choice B also includes the question?

Comment: No, just as it is stated.

Comment: If it matters, I don't expect to have more than 5 questions of this type on the form (more likely 3).

Comment: What do you do when there's more than one visibility type? Public turns into friends only, or contractors only, or realtors only. This is a nightmare waiting to happen! Prepare for it now!

Comment: For this application and this particular feature, that's not a likely possibility right now.  If we needed to expand in the future, I would imagine a block of multiple-select checkboxes with opinionated defaults.

Comment: And as far as a "nightmare", I would think that growing to need the extra capability past an MVP is a great problem to have :)

Comment: It's very important to know if these are optional or required questions as well... By the nature of the question I would have to assume they are required?

Comment: Yes, this would be required.  Updated the question.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### Neither.

### Settings are different from questions.

This may seem obvious, but it drives a difference in UX design. Yes and No may be reasonable answers to a question:

> Are you a muggle?  Yes / No

However, in your case you are really asking the user to **make a setting**.
For settings, don't make the user think too much:

- **Describe what the radio button does** instead of leading with yes/no.  A yes/no is cognitively more complicated because the user has to relate yes/no back to the question, so she may have to scan back up to re-establish context with the question (users pay less attention than you think).
- **Avoid long unbroken lines of text**.  You are asking users to read too much text to make a simple setting.  It's better to provide a short (1 to 3 words) summary of what the selection does.

A more modern approach to this radio button setting:

[image]

Comment: For years, the standard example of a "set in stone, two value question" was male/female. Nowadays you can't even use a radio box for that - you need a multiselect.

Comment: +1.  I like this answer overall and the concept first posed by @rewobs.  What I was trying to avoid, however, is use of the word "private" since that could be misleading.  Perhaps "Unlisted" would be a better choice and this structure can lend itself to eventually offering "Private" as a third option.  I'm going to keep this question open to stew a bit longer.

Comment: @corsiKa I work at a medical company and just recently had to add a 3rd radio box for "I'd rather not say" on the Gender question of our sign up form. You would think that would be a pretty standard question to answer honestly to your doctor right?...

Comment: @bphilipnyc sounds good.  I think `Unlisted` may work. One thing that may help is to stick to design principles...if you believe the design logic above, then the issue becomes *what word to choose* rather than restructuring the whole layout into a question just to avoid using one word.

Comment: @tohster have a checkmark, my friend

Comment: The "modern" approach is 100 times better. People are used to public/private words these days thanks to facebook, github, etc.

Comment: @bfritz, what about intersex people? They can't answer neither “male” nor “female”, even in an strictly medical context.

Comment: The setting implies that you decide whether this is going to be a public or private listing before you even start writing the listing. I personally wouldn't like that as a user. What's the point of having a private listing? Is it a draft listing? or a way to take down a listing temporarily? Can the user change that decision later?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk take a look at the privacy options at youtube.  It's the same concept.

Answer (score 10):

As you mentioned if the option B doesn't include the question I would go with A) because **the question is simply enough** to admit a Yes/No answer, plus the explanation next to the option is the expected and not something that **really** needs to be cleared before the user accept, the question already states the final consequence.

Also, you could use an **alternative approach**, that for me is clearer:
(FYI English is not my native language, so use the words that suit better)

```
Visibility of list property :   
( ) Public.  Make the property viewable from my home page.   
( ) Hidden.  Hide the property from my home page.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the radio select into a check box and provide a tool tip with additional information about the option (i.e. public = visible on homepage)

Comment: Not a bad idea per se, but a checkbox implies a default value.

Comment: How does a checkbox imply a default value?

Comment: If a page is loaded with a checkbox named "public" and is checked, it implies that it is public by default.  If it is loaded as unchecked, it is implied as private by default.  Does that make sense?  You can make the user *choose* consciously with a radio button before proceeding as it can be unselected.

Comment: Or technically, if it is unchecked it is *not public* by default

Comment: @bphilipnyc And most users prefer defaults! People are inherently lazy, and each incremental step in a process reduces the probability that it will be completed, filling out optional questions on a form is defiantly one of the places this is shown the most.

Comment: Ha, based on your comment, @bfritz, maybe I should make it an unselected radio button, track which item the users are clicking and set that one as the default.

Answer (score 2):

The questions being asked are yes/no questions. The appropriate UI control to use in a yes/no aka Boolean configuration setting or question would be a checkbox.

[x] List this property publicly.

[x] Show this property on my home page.

Both (a) and (b) choices are potentially confusing to a user and should not be framed using a 'radio' UI control at all.

If it's not clear that all property listings are private by default, then communicate that somewhere as well (but not as part of a UI control label).

Comment: I fully support this answer! The whole Yes/No questions on forms is very dated and lots of people have moved past this and with better framing and results using checkboxes for every sort of implementation from configuration settings to Opt-In/Opt-Out notifications etc. Just check some of the configuration screens for Google/Amazon/Microsoft/Paypal etc. I recently just had to convey this exact issue with my company and did a bunch of research and decided to go with checkboxes as well.

Comment: On mobile the on/off toggle switch is also an appropriate UI element.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example question provided here are a couple considerations that may help you make a decision.

**Scaling**

Example A removes the bulk of the question from the answer choices and puts it above them, this makes question have less width but more height. So if you intend to make this application scale to mobile devices this would be preferable as it will fit the smaller screens better and you will have less wrapping issues.

**Repetition**

Another reason I find Example A preferable is the repetition of what youre choosing between seems redundant (i.e. in this example "*List property publicly*", "do not *list property publicly*", since these choices are always directly opposing you will always be essentially reading the question twice as opposed to once and then choosing.

**Separation of content**

With the question above the answer choices it acts as a sort of header to show where the question begins and the last question ended. With no question above it could appear as you just have a wall of answers with no separation. (NOTE: this assumes you're not separating the questions another way such as borders or blocks)

So in my opinion Example A is the better choice. But in the end all that really matters is consistency, pick one and stick with it.